# Windows 10 taskbar doesn't show number of messages received by Skype App

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, skype, notifications, windows-store-app

I am using Windows 10, and the Skype App that came with it. (Not Skype for Business.)

I have its icon in the taskbar.

But when I get a message, the taskbar icon doesn't change to show me that I received a message.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to get it to show that a message was received.

(Note: This will work for future messages, but not retroactively.)

In the Start Menu, I right click on Skype > More > Turn Live Tile On.

[image]

Then on the next message you get, it will show that 1 message was received:

[image]

**UPDATE:**
This does NOT always work. The notification count does not always appear. I recommend switching to Classic Skype (aka "Skype for Windows") if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on"Show badges on taskbar buttons".  The icon still does not flash, but you get a number bubble of the number of new messages you have.  Setting>Personalization>taskbar